# Cannot add new collection in mongodb in mLab

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, passport.js, mlab

I am following full-stack react course by stephen grider. Everything looks good but after google social auth, I can't see new `users` collection getting added to the mLab database.

I am using passport.js and mongoose.js.

Here is the relevant source code:

*index.js*

```
const express = require('express');
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const keys = require('./config/keys');
require('./models/User');
require('./services/passport');

mongoose.connect(keys.mongoURI);

const app = express();

require('./routes/authRoutes')(app);

const PORT = process.env.PORT || 5000;
app.listen(PORT)
```

*user.js*

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const { Schema } = mongoose;

const userSchema = new Schema({
  googleId: String
});

mongoose.model('users', userSchema);
```

*passport.js*

```
const passport = require('passport');
const GoogleStrategy = require('passport-google-oauth20').Strategy;
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const keys = require('../config/keys');

const User = mongoose.model('users');

passport.use(
  new GoogleStrategy(
    {
      clientID: keys.googleClientID,
      clientSecret: keys.googleClientSecret,
      callbackURL: '/auth/google/callback'
    },
    (accessToken, refreshToken, profile, done) => {
      new User({ googleId: profile.id }).save();
      console.log('accessToken',accessToken,'profile',profile)
    }
  )
);
```

Could anyone please let me know where I am making mistake because of which new collection is not getting created in the MongoDB database?

Comment: I do not see the `module.export` in your `User` schema (user.js).

Comment: @AnkitAgarwal could you tell me what to export from it? Can't we access users directly?

Comment: Replace `mongoose.model('users', userSchema);` with `module.export = mongoose.model('users', userSchema);` and try. As you need to export the `model` so that it can be used in your `passport.js` file.

Comment: here you have a example https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49547992/nodejs-mongodb-dont-woking-on-server/49548108#49548108

Comment: @AnkitAgarwal. no, still it's not working bro. :(

Comment: @VikasYadav What's the error you are getting now?

Comment: @VikasYadav It could also be the error in your mongodb connection. You should be sure that connection works perfectly

Comment: @AnkitAgarawal. No. I am not getting any error. It's just new collection should update in the mLab database. How can I check whether mongodb is connected or not?

Comment: Try `module.exportS` instead of `module.export`.

Comment: It worked. Thanks, everybody. I will update the answer for this.

Comment: Unrelated: in the edit queue, I came across a question that you voted on in triage. Wrong choice. Please: study the help for triage really carefully, and avoid putting items into the edit queue that don't belong there. ( I am specifically talking about https://stackoverflow.com/review/triage/20882811 ). Please understand that your votes have consequences and be more careful about your input!

Comment: ok but why are you telling it here @GhostCat

Comment: Because I want to make sure that you see the message. I cant use @VikasYadav in the **original** question, so I have to turn to a place where I can directly reach you. Therefore my comment starts with "Unrelated" ;-)

Comment: oh ok. Thanks. I will be more careful from now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue was in the user.js file. Defining Schema alone doesn't work. You will need to export it too.

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const { Schema } = mongoose;

const userSchema = new Schema({
  googleId: String
});

module.exports = mongoose.model('users', userSchema);
```

Further, if anybody come across this type of error, please make sure you are using correct credentials(username and password) for the particular mongo database.

Answer (score 0):

If your DB password contain **`@`** on mLab it won't work
Remove and try again it will work